# Bootstrap messed up button with link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a navigation bar in bootstrap with a button that links to another page where you can login (I'm still working on that login part) But as soon as i put the link (Href) between the button the whole navbar gets messed up. I can show an example with picture's

1. This is the normal version: http://prntscr.com/cq09nx
2. This is the messed up version: http://prntscr.com/cq09io

I just can't figure out how to get it right again. 
Here is the HTML Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #42A2CE;
}
 ::selection {
  background: white;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Nexa Light";
  src: url('../font/Nexa%20Light.otf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato-Bold";
  src: url('../font/Lato-Bold.ttf');
}
.navbar-default {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Lato-Bold";
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
}
.navbar-header {
  right: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li {} .navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #FFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: grey;
}
.icon-bar {} .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 45);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.col-md-5 {
  font-family: "Lato-Bold";
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.col-md-12 {
  font-family: "Lato-Bold";
  height: 520px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  border: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  ;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover {
  color: rgb(44, 44, 45);
}
.img-responsive {
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#footer {
  height: 200px;
  color: lightgrey;
}
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightgrey;
}
.link:hover {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
.btn-primary.raised {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #007299;
}
.btn-primary.raised:active,
.btn-primary.raised.active {
  background: #33a6cc;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.btn {
  padding: 14px 24px;
  border: 0 none;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}
.btn-primary {
  background: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background: #33a6cc;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
  background: #007299;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-primary.raised:active,
.btn-primary.raised.active {
  background: #33a6cc;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.navbar-right {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Niet beschikbaar</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATIE BALK -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!--  -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Logo
      </a>

      <!-- Inklappbaar ding als je op mobiel zit-->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- menu eitems  linker kant-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="paginas/overmij/index.html">Over mij</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <!-- Dropdown -->
        <!--
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profiel <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Profiel</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Instellingen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        -->
        <li>
          <a href="paginas/login/index.html">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised">Aanmelden</button>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <!-- Aan de rechterkant -->


  </nav>

  <!-- EINDE NAVIAGTIE BALK-->



  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1 class="titel">Deze website is helaas nog niet beschikbaar</h1>
        Er word momenteel gewerkt aan deze website. Probeer op een later moment terug te komen. Er wordt echt heel erg hard gewerkt aan deze website, zo hard zelfs dat het waarschijnelijk nooit af komt. Maar dat boeit niemand want niemand bezoekt deze website.
        Deze website is alleen bekeken door mensen die ik ken. Want niemand is geintresseert in mijn website wat ik heel klote vindt. Wat ik ook niet begrijp is dat je nog door leest

        <br>
        <br>Rainier,
        <img src="img/Maintance.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="float:right" />
        <br>
        <br>

        <!--
      </div>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm just a beginner in bootstrap as you can tell. I hope you guys can help me out with this. Thank you in advance

Rainier,

Comment: You have unclosed div tag in nav bar as well as 3 unclosed div in given code.

Comment: let me know if my answer below works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the classes to the link directly, no need for a button element:

```
<li>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised" href="paginas/login/index.html">
    Aanmelden
  </a>
</li>
```

Try if this helps.

Also, this post seems to describe the same problem:

[Adding href to one button in btn-toolbar and maintaining alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702168)

Comment: I tried that already but it didnt work. Thats why i'm asking ;-). The button just clicks with no link.

Comment: I got it working now. but the button is now a bit messed up. Its still blue but the letters are black and on hover the button turns white. I tried this in the HTML                                                                                         <li><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised" class="aanmelden" href="../login/index.html">
          Aanmelden
        </a></li>

Comment: And this with the CSS:                                                            .aanmelden {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

Comment: @RainierLaan Yea, unfortunately this link is inside a navbar, so some styles get overridden with bootstrap's navbar styles. You can add some rules to set the color/behavior back to the way you want.

Comment: I got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see here > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdcurw7o/) or code snippet bellow

remove `padding-top` from the last `li a` ( which is the button )

```
 .navbar-nav li:last-child a { padding-top:0;}
```

or you could assign a class to the last `li` and and then style that class

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #42A2CE;
}

::selection{
background: white;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Nexa Light";
src: url('../font/Nexa%20Light.otf');
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato-Bold";
src: url('../font/Lato-Bold.ttf');
}

.navbar-default {
position: relative;
font-family: "Lato-Bold";
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 20px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
font-size: 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
         box-shadow: 0 12px 8px -6px #999;
 }

.navbar-header{
right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: grey;

}

.icon-bar {

}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 45);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.col-md-5 {
font-family: "Lato-Bold";
padding: 10px;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}

.col-md-12 {
font-family: "Lato-Bold";
height: 520px;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
}

.navbar-collapse {
 border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
border-color: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
background-color: transparent;;
text-decoration-color: black;
}


.dropdown-toggle {
background-color: transparent;
color: black;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,.navbar-default   .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover {
color: rgb(44, 44, 45);
}

.img-responsive {
text-align: right;
max-width: 100%;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

#footer {
height: 200px;
color: lightgrey;
}

.link {
text-decoration: none;
color: lightgrey;
}

.link:hover {
color: yellow;
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.42857143;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 10px 16px;
}

.btn-lg {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.33;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-primary {
color: #fff;
background-color: #428bca;
border-color: #357ebd;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
color: #fff;
background-color: #3276b1;
border-color: #285e8e;
}

.btn-primary.raised {
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #007299;
}
.btn-primary.raised:active, .btn-primary.raised.active {
background: #33a6cc;
box-shadow: none;
margin-bottom: -3px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

.btn {
padding: 14px 24px;
border: 0 none;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-primary {
background: #0099cc;
color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
background: #33a6cc;
}
.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
background: #007299;
box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary.raised:active, .btn-primary.raised.active {
background: #33a6cc;
box-shadow: none;
margin-bottom: -3px;
margin-top: 3px;
}


.navbar-right {
padding-right: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
padding-left: 50px;
}

.img-responsive {
display: block;
height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav li:last-child a {
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- logo -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <!--  -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    Logo
  </a>

  <!-- Inklappbaar ding als je op mobiel zit-->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  </div>

<!-- menu eitems  linker kant-->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/overmij/index.html">Over mij</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <!--
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profiel <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profiel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Instellingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    -->
    <li><a href="paginas/login/index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised">Aanmelden</button></a></li>
  </ul>


  <!-- Aan de rechterkant -->


</nav>

<!-- EINDE NAVIAGTIE BALK-->



<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1 class="titel">Deze website is helaas nog niet beschikbaar</h1>
      Er word momenteel gewerkt aan deze website. Probeer op een later moment terug te komen.
      Er wordt echt heel erg hard gewerkt aan deze website, zo hard zelfs dat het waarschijnelijk nooit af komt.
      Maar dat boeit niemand want niemand bezoekt deze website. Deze website is alleen bekeken door mensen die ik ken.
      Want niemand is geintresseert in mijn website wat ik heel klote vindt. Wat ik ook niet begrijp is dat je nog door leest

      <br>
      <br>
      Rainier,
      <img src="img/Maintance.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="float:right"/>
      <br>
      <br>

      <!--
  </div>
```